# Proof verification: if $f,g: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous and$f=g$ a.e. then $f=g$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions on $[a,b]$. Show that if $f=g$ a.e. on $[a,b]$, then, in fact, $f=g$ on $[a,b]$. Is a similar assertion true if $[a,b]$ is replaced by a general measurable set $E$?

OK. So here's my thought:

Set $A = \{ x \in [a,b]: f(x) \neq g(x)\}$, we're going to show that $A = \emptyset$.

We have $A = \{ x \in [a,b]: f(x) - g(x) \neq 0\} = [a,b] - \{ x \in [a,b]: f(x)-g(x)=0 \}=[a,b]-B$.

Since $f$ and $g$ both are continuous on $[a,b]$ the function $(f-g)(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ is well-defined on $[a,b]$ and is continuous. Therefore, since $B = (f-g)^{-1}(\{0\})$ and singletons are closed in a metric space, we conclude that $B$ is a closed set in $[a,b]$ and therefore $A$ is an open set in $[a,b]$.

The non-empty open sets in $[a,b]$ are one of these forms: $[a,x)$, $(x,b]$, $(x,y)$ or $[a,b]$ itself for $x<y \in (a,b)$ or we can have a union of these sets. The measure of all these sets is positive. Hence, contradiction. So, $A$ must be equal to the empty set. Q.E.D.

For the second part, if my proof is correct, then since I never used the fact that $[a,b]$ is closed, compact or any special set, I think we can generalize the proof to general measurable sets as long as they contain an open set.  Am  I right?

For example, if $E$ is the Cantor set, we can't generalize our proof to $E$.

Am I right?

*I'm using the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Whatever I say here is supposed to be true when we're using the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, not other possible measures.*

Comment: The main point is that full measure sets are dense (for Radon measures), and continuous functions are uniquely determined by their values on dense subsets.

Comment: I suspect that this exercise is leading up to a proof of that theorem...it would be if *I* were teaching the course.

Comment: @AdamHughes: I didn't know that full measure sets were dense. But actually it seems easy to prove that. Because if $E \subset X$ and $m(E)=m(X)$ then for any point $x \in X$ and any open ball centered at $x$ like $N_{\epsilon}(x)$ we must have $N_{\epsilon}(x) \cap E \neq 0$ otherwise $N_{\epsilon}(x) \subset E^{c}$ and $E^{c}$ will have a positive measure but $m(E^c)=0$, hence the contradiction. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, the point is that Radon measures assign positive measure to open sets, so that if you have a full measure set, it's complement has measure $0$, hence cannot contain any open sets.

Comment: @AdamHughes: OK. Thanks. I don't know about Radon measures yet. So far I know only the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. I'm self-studying real analysis from Royden's real analysis and it doesn't talk about abstract measures in the first chapters.

Comment: It doesn't really matter, the property I'm alluding to is just that open sets have positive measure, which Lebesgue satisfies (that's enough for this exercise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof goes wrong here "The non-empty open sets in [a,b] are one of these forms: [a,x), (x,b], (x,y) or [a,b] itself..."

That statement about open sets is just wrong. For instance, the union of any two such sets is also open. What IS true is that every open set contains a set of one of those three types. And if it contains $[a, x)$, it also contains $( \frac{a+x}{2}, x)$. So it alwasy contains one of the third type, whose measure is positive.

For your second part: what can you say about a measurable set that contains an open set? 
Also: would the statement be true if your set, was, say, the Cantor set $E$ together with the interval $(0, 0.1)$? Or do you need something MORE about open sets in relation to your set?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry. I was only naming the open sets that form a basis for the subspace topology on $[a,b]$. And as you showed we can throw out $[a,x)$ or $(x,b]$. The point is that any non-empty open set in $[a,b]$ has a positive measure, therefore $A=\emptyset$. I don't get what you're asking about the second part.

Comment: You wrote " I think we can generalize the proof to general measurable sets as long as they contain an open set" and then observed that the proof would not work for $E$, and I asked if it'd work for $E \cup (0, 0.1)$. The answer's "no"; for your proof to work, you need a *positive-measure* open set about any point. Your proof won't work for the integers with the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb R$, because every set $\{n\}$ is open, but doesn't have positive measure (in $\mathbb R$).

Comment: Yes, you're right. I guess it's my bad that I didn't mention the level of abstraction I'm dealing with yet. I'm following Royden's real analysis and so far it has talked only about Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$. But $\mathbb{Z}$ with the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$ gets the discrete topology and I think Royden hasn't talked about that yet. But nevertheless, the discrete topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ was a very good example to keep in mind for later. Am I still missing something?

Comment: Nope. Sounds as if you're on the right track. Actually, the rationals with the subspace topology are another good example to keep in mind, too.

Answer (score 1):

Your description of the non-empty open sets is wrong, but you could easily correct your argument by saying that if $A\neq \emptyset$, then it contains an open ball thus it has positive measure.

Actually, a necessary and sufficient condition on a measurable set $E$ to satisfy your property is that every nonempty open set in $E$ has positive measure.

Comment: Thank you. So, as long as I'm dealing with the Lebesgue measure, my reasoning for the second part is fine. Right?

Comment: Not exactly : for instance if $E$ has an isolated point then clearly this point is both open and closed, and you can't deduce anything on this point.

Another simple example is if $E$ is of null measure, like your example of the Cantor set.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can make the proof easier and with little (or basic) measure theory: suppose $\;w\in [a,b]\;$ is s.t. $\;f(w)\neq g(w)\;$ .

Since, as noted by you, the function $\;h(x):=(f-g)(x):=f(x)-g(x)\;$ is continuous and $\;h(w)\neq 0\;$ , there exists an open neighborhood $\;U_w\;$ of $\;w\;$, $\;U_w\subset [a,b]\;$ ( this is a one-sided open neighborhood if $\;w=a\;\;or\;\;w=b\;$) s.t. $\;h(x)\neq 0\;\;\forall\,x\in U_w\;$

But this can't be since this means $\;f(x)\neq g(x)\;\;\;\forall\,x\in U_w\;$ and $\;|U_w|>0\;$ .

Comment: I think this is essentially the same argument I wrote.

Comment: It is, but this proof introduces fewer new symbols (your $A$ and $B$) and gets to the point faster. The ideas are the same, but the presentation cleaner. For most proofs, rewriting after you work them out is a pretty good idea, esp. early in your proof-writing practice. (I've been doing it for about 45 years, and still routinely rewrite proofs, just as I rewrite correct code sometimes when I'm programming.)

Comment: @math.n00b, I don't think the above is at all essentially what you wrote. Of course, different proofs of the same thing can have common points.

Comment: Well, I think it only introduces fewer new symbols and gets to the point faster, because it avoids unnecessary explanations I added, but it's exactly the same argument. You say $f-g$ is continuous and then show that the set of points that $f \neq g$ contains an open set and since open sets have positive Lebesgue measure it must be empty. I don't see how that isn't the same argument.

Comment: Well @math.n00b, easing down, simplifying, rewording and using other ideas or the same ideas but from another place is precisely giving **another** argument, imo. My answer has no topology/metric spaces, singletons, inverse images and stuff. For me, that is different.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direct proof for the first part (which is along the lines of Adam Hughes' comment):

Since $f=g$ ae, $\exists N\subseteq [a,b]: m(N)=0, \forall x\in N^c: f(x)=g(x)$. We claim that $f=g$ on $N$ also. Let $x\in N$. Observe that $N$ does not contain any open interval centered at $x$, otherwise it couldn't have zero measure. Then $\exists \{x_n\}_n\subseteq N^c: x_n\to x$. Since both $f$ and $g$ are continuous, $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ and $g(x_n)\to g(x)$. Since $f$ and $g$ coincide on $N^c$, $\forall n: f(x_n)=g(x_n)$, so that $f(x)=g(x)$.

---

For the second part, take $E:=\{0\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}, f(0):=1, g(0):=-1$. Then $m(\{f\neq g\})=m(E)=0$ and $f$ and $g$ are both continuous but $f\neq g$.