# Understanding the condition $f =g $ a.e. on $E$ in the following example.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to solve the second part of the following question:

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions on $[a,b].$ Show that if $f = g$ a.e. on $[a,b],$ then, in fact, $f = g$ on $[a,b].$ Is a similar assertion true if $[a,b]$ is replaced by a general measurable set $E$?

But I got confused by the answer of Alp Uzman here
[Proof verification: if $f,g: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous and$f=g$ a.e. then $f=g$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/971663/proof-verification-if-f-g-a-b-to-mathbbr-are-con) about the second part, where he said the following:

"For the second part, take $E:=\{0\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}, f(0):=1, g(0):=-1$. Then $m(\{f\neq g\})=m(E)=0$ and $f$ and $g$ are both continuous but $f\neq g$."

So I am not sure why his $E$ satisfies the condition that $f = g$ a.e. on $E.$ Also, I am not sure why choosing a set of measure $0$ will help us construct a counterexample.

Any elaboration will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your doubt or what are your doubts?

Comment: Do you know what a.e. means?

Comment: @311411  I just feel that it is not $f=g$ a.e. on $E,$ it is that $f\neq g$ on all of $E,$ there is no place in $E$ that they are the same.

Comment: @Joe yeah,  I just feel that it is not $f=g$ a.e. on $E,$ it is that $f\neq g$ on all of $E,$ there is no place in $E$ that they are the same.

Comment: The set of points on which they differ has measure zero. Something holding a.e. doesn't tell you the measure of the set on which it holds, it tells you that the set of points on which it does not hold is a subset of a set of measure zero.

Comment: So what confusing here is that it holds on a set of measure zero and it does not hold on a set of measure zero also?@Joe

Comment: Or do you mean that this example does not specify the set upon which $f=g$? if so, can this be considered as a complete example?@Joe

Comment: The set upon which $f=g$ is only relevant to the extent that it helps identify the set upon which $f\ne g$. The latter needs to be contained in a set of measure zero for $f=g$ a.e.  I agree that it's very counterintuitive and odd having the set $f=g$ have measure zero (in this case, the empty set), but I wouldn't call it confusing ***if*** you ignore your intuition and instead just go by the definition of a.e. If you do that, I think it's very clear. Often in math I think that we can find something confusing not because it is actually confusing, but because it goes against our intuition.

Comment: See also [Does the statement "$f = 0$ almost everywhere" depend on the measure that is defined?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1037205/does-the-statement-f-0-almost-everywhere-depend-on-the-measure-that-is-def)

Comment: "$f=g$ a.e. on $E$" means $m(\, \{x\in E: f(x)\ne g(x)\}\,)=0$.  This holds if $m(E)=0$ for $any$ $f.g$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet does it follows the logic implication rule, which says, if the premises is always false then the conclusion is always true(as our $E$ here is the empty set)?

Comment: The example $E=\{0\}$ in your Q is not empty. And in my comment $m(E)=0$ but $E$ need not be empty. But if $E$ $is$ empty then  obviously $\{x∈E:f(x)≠g(x)\}$ is a set  of measure $0$.